# ReactiveMongo and Play framework: error ConnectionNotInitialized

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm trying to follow the tutorial of "reactiveMongo" with play framework and scala, but I get the following error:

```
[ConnectionNotInitialized: MongoError['Connection is missing metadata (like protocol version, etc.) The connection pool is probably being initialized.']]
```

My application.conf haves:

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoModule"
mongodb.uri ="mongodb://localhost:27017/cambio"
```

My build.sbt haves:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.5-play26"
```

**My mongo is start.**

My controller is:

```
package controllers

    import javax.inject.Inject

    import scala.concurrent.Future

    import play.api.Logger
    import play.api.mvc.{ Action, Controller }
    import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
    import play.api.libs.json._

    // Reactive Mongo imports
    import reactivemongo.api.Cursor
    import reactivemongo.api.ReadPreference

    import play.modules.reactivemongo.{ // ReactiveMongo Play2 plugin
      MongoController,
      ReactiveMongoApi,
      ReactiveMongoComponents
    }

    // BSON-JSON conversions/collection
    import reactivemongo.play.json._
    import play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection._

    /*
     * Example using ReactiveMongo + Play JSON library.
     *
     * There are two approaches demonstrated in this controller:
     * - using JsObjects directly
     * - using case classes that can be turned into JSON using Reads and Writes.
     *
     * This controller uses JsObjects directly.
     *
     * Instead of using the default Collection implementation (which interacts with
     * BSON structures + BSONReader/BSONWriter), we use a specialized
     * implementation that works with JsObject + Reads/Writes.
     *
     * Of course, you can still use the default Collection implementation
     * (BSONCollection.) See ReactiveMongo examples to learn how to use it.
     */
    class UserController @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)
        extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {

      /*
       * Get a JSONCollection (a Collection implementation that is designed to work
       * with JsObject, Reads and Writes.)
       * Note that the `collection` is not a `val`, but a `def`. We do _not_ store
       * the collection reference to avoid potential problems in development with
       * Play hot-reloading.
       */
      def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("broker")

      def index = Action { Ok("works") }

      def create(name: String, age: Int) = Action.async {
        val json = Json.obj(
          "name" -> name,
          "age" -> age,
          "created" -> new java.util.Date().getTime())

        collection.insert(json).map(lastError =>
          Ok("Mongo LastError: %s".format(lastError)))
      }

      def createFromJson = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
        import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
        /*
         * request.body is a JsValue.
         * There is an implicit Writes that turns this JsValue as a JsObject,
         * so you can call insert() with this JsValue.
         * (insert() takes a JsObject as parameter, or anything that can be
         * turned into a JsObject using a Writes.)
         */
        val transformer: Reads[JsObject] =
          Reads.jsPickBranch[JsString](__ \ "firstName") and
            Reads.jsPickBranch[JsString](__ \ "lastName") and
            Reads.jsPickBranch[JsNumber](__ \ "age") reduce

        request.body.transform(transformer).map { result =>
          collection.insert(result).map { lastError =>
            Logger.debug(s"Successfully inserted with LastError: $lastError")
            Created
          }
        }.getOrElse(Future.successful(BadRequest("invalid json")))
      }

      def findByName(name: String) = Action.async {
        // let's do our query
        val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = collection.
          // find all people with name `name`
          find(Json.obj("name" -> name)).
          // sort them by creation date
          sort(Json.obj("created" -> -1)).
          // perform the query and get a cursor of JsObject
          cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)

        // gather all the JsObjects in a list
        val futurePersonsList: Future[List[JsObject]] = cursor.collect[List]()

        // transform the list into a JsArray
        val futurePersonsJsonArray: Future[JsArray] =
          futurePersonsList.map { persons => Json.arr(persons) }

        // everything's ok! Let's reply with the array
        futurePersonsJsonArray.map { broker =>
          Ok(broker)
        }
      }
    }
```

My routes is:

```
# Routes
    # This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
    # ~~~~

    # An example controller showing a sample home page
    GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
    GET     /crear/:name/:age           controllers.UserController.create(name: String, age: Int)
    GET     /buscar/:name           controllers.UserController.findByName(name: String)

    # Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
    GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Comment: does your mongo instance require the client to authenticate?

Comment: No. I just follow the basic tutorial: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html
But I get that error, and it does not save any data in mongodb. When I use db.broker.find().

Comment: I'm talking about mongodb itself. Does it require clients to authenticate? How did you do that setup? Can you connect via command line? Which version are you using?

Comment: No, I did not create any user, it does not require.
The mongod version is: version db v3.4.6
The mongod shell starts well:
2017-07-17T17: 08: 11.873-0500 I NETWORK [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45660 # 10 (10 connections now open)

Comment: You are using the deprecated `.db` controller function, instead of the `.database` one (also see [database resolution](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/release-details.html#database-resolution)).

Comment: Hi, I do not understand, what should I replace? Thanks.

Comment: Check the `def collection` according previous comment.

Comment: It not working. I dont use /conf/play.plugin
http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html

Comment: It's weird, because sometimes when I go to the path I "crear/:name:/:age", and I see in the shell the collections appear, but then they disappear, they are erased, it's as if they are not saved. What's going on?

Comment: `ConnectionNotInitialised` is the cause, due to db resolution as suggested in comments

Comment: Not work. Even execute this:
Https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/reactivemongo-demo-app
However, it does not save the data in mongodb. When I put db.articles.find() in the shell, it appears empty, only the data appears in the localhost: 9000

Comment: The demo app is working fine, so I would suggest you check the comments and the changes you've made.

Comment: I did not make any changes, I did "sbt run" with the demo per se. Could it be a problem with mongo? Because in localhost: 9000 if I see the articles created. However when putting db.articles.count () or db.articles.find () in the shell does not show me any data, it is as if they were not written but persists in the browser.